# Code splitting in Next JS 3 to get smaller bundle size in Lighthouse

Tags: javascript, performance, next.js, lighthouse, code-splitting

I had an app under Next Js 3.2.3 which I currently analyze and improve to get higher score in Google Lighthouse. It currently receive bad audit on JS bundle size, which shows that 90% of the main bundled and minified code in /_app.js is too large (600KB) and can be optimized.
One of the way is through code splitting, but I'm not sure if it's possible in my current version of Next JS, and upgrading version is not currently an option.

My question is :

1. Is there any way to implement this manually without Next JS code splitting plugin ?
2. Is there another way other that code splitting to reduce bundle size ?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but I would highly recommend you upgrade to a more recent version of Next.js. The version you're on is over 3 years old and could potentially bring you more issues down the line.

Comment: @juliomalves I couldn't agree more. Next js indeed introduces a lot of improvement performance-wise, to their library and production side generation code on their latest version, but, its currently, and potentially would cause more issue to update the whole nextjs library to latest version because of broken dependencies that I actually have, than actually fixing the optimization problem. Thanks for the suggestion anw!